# Silverlight penetration rate

Tags: silverlight, plugins

#### Duplicate of: [Silverlight Install Base - How big is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121/silverlight-install-base-how-big-is-it)

---

Hi,
Anyone knows the penetration rate (in %) for all North-American internet users with the Silverlight plugin installed? Been looking all around, but couldn't find any comprehensive numbers.

I'm looking for General Public penetration rates, **not only within the dev community**. Something close to [Adobe's flash version penetration stats](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html) would be great.

Comment: Silverlight Install Base has some information about the dev community install rates.  I'm looking at the general, joe the plumber, install rates.

Comment: @sthg: AFAIK, so was Tyler on that other question. Unfortunately, no one has been able to provide concrete data so far...

Comment: Maybe we should just poll Joe the Plumber since he seems to be the representative sample. That would give you 0 or 100% adoption :)

Comment: although this is a duplicate of that other question, this one has a better title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight Install Base - How big is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121/silverlight-install-base-how-big-is-it)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best I can find are:

http://riastats.com

and:

http://www.statowl.com/custom_ria_market_penetration.php

Both have Silverlight at around 20%.

**Update one year later:  Both sites now show Silverlight penetration around 55%**

Comment: riastats now have silverlight at around %28.  So 7 months and 8 percent increase.

Comment: 20% to 28% is a 40% increase.

Comment: Riastats now has Silverlight 3 at 44%.  If that's accurate, it's certainly made a huge jump this year.

Comment: As of Feb 2011 Silverlight is at 71% (Just as much as Java)

Comment: look at the new cool kid in the game HTML 5 ... (canvas and Video close to it :P )

Comment: @BenAlpert 40% increase relative to previous.  8% increase relative to total market.  While the former makes sense for numbers with no limit (such as stock prices), the latter can be much clearer when the total is unchanging (which is always the case with percentages— a percent is just a way of specifying “relative to the total”).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft reckons over 100 million Silverlight plugin downloads, but I'm not sure how that translates into percentages. Still definitely lower than Flash. Have a look at [this blog](http://www.silverlight-travel.com/blog/tag/microsoft-silverlight/) for some more in-depth info.

Dont forget that MS can push Silverlight out over Windows Update to immediately reach millions of PCs. (That doesnt help Mac users though) Pushing it via Windows Update will also reach all the "Joe the Plumber" users who may not be comfortable installing plugins themselves

The real challenge for them is to get a decent base of Silverlight apps that people will want to get the plugin for. Bit of a chicken-and-egg problem there.

I see Silverlight probably having more success as a platform for intranet web apps in large companies (I'm building one at the moment).

Comment: Thanks. This blog had a link to RIASTATS, http://riastats.com/ which shows good stats about install rates.

Comment: They already do push SL over Microsoft Update but it is listed as optional.

Answer (score 2):

On the [December 12, 2008 podcast of DotNetRocks](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=404), Richard and Carl interviewed Tim Heuer who is a product manager on the Silverlight team at microsoft. What surprised me is that Tim said,

> Yeah, it's really good. Yeah, I
>   think that's probably an accurate number. I think a lot
>   of the PR term I keep hearing is every one in four
>   people in the world have access to a machine with
>   Silverlight.

Source: http://perseus.franklins.net/dotnetrocks_0404_tim_heuer.pdf (page 14)

One in four have ***access*** to a machine with Silverlight, that's not exactly the same as one in four machines have Silverlight.  I'd assume the adoption base has gone up since December, but that quote tells me that at that point and time, the adoption rate was below 25%.  If so, that would lend support to what webdtc found with a Silverlight adoption of 20%.

Answer (score 1):

I believe penetration percentage is absolutely useless against actual stats of your user base.

We have lot of mac users and still 25% of them are PowerPC, and silverlight doesnt come for PowerPC, now we can not tell our customers to go ahead and buy $1000 to $1500 new intel mac, they will say good bye to us because they have other vendors.

Silverlight is good, but honestly its only for windows users, if its available you can tell your users to download it and install it. But I think we need to wait 2-3 years, by the time, silverlight can be available and stable for bigger user base.

Answer (score 0):

Adoption seems to grow about 2 percent per month, so if this continues you could expect about 40 percent by the end of the year. Hopefully the fact that the NCAA tournament is using Silverlight and then the release of Silverlight 3 hopefully sometime later this year will accelerate that rate.